# How do I get the return code of a command in a pipe, run as a background process?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, error-handling

Within a Bash script, if I run a command within a pipe the special parameter `$?` will contain the return code of the last command in the pipe. For instance, with an intentionally failing `rsync` command, I get the return code of the `tee` command:

```
$ rsync /non-existent-dir/ /another-dir2/ 2>&1 | tee outfile1 > outfile2
$ echo $?
0
```

I can get the return code of the `rsync` command by using the first entry in the special array which contains the return codes of the last pipe `$PIPESTATUS`

```
$ rsync /non-existent-dir/ /another-dir2/ 2>&1 | tee outfile1 > outfile2
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
23
```

Normally if I background a task, I can use `wait` to collect its return code, as `wait` will mirror the return code of the background task it's waiting for.

```
$ rsync /non-existent-dir/ /another-dir2/ 2>&1 > outfile1 &
$ wait $!
$ echo $?
23
```

I can't seem to combine these two methods to capture the return code if the background process includes a pipe? I have a feeling that combining the methods is not the way to do this, and I need to use a different approach.

How do I execute a command like the following, and collect the return code of the first command?

```
$ rsync /non-existent-dir/ /another-dir2/ 2>&1 | tee outfile1 > outfile2 &
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the PIPESTATUS variable inside the background process:

```
$ { rsync /non-existent-dir/ /another-dir2/ 2>&1 | tee outfile1 > outfile2 ; echo $PIPESTATUS } &
```

If you only want to know the exit status of the rsync command, you can simply use `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` instead of the echo command. Otherwise you will have to use a temp file.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50754377/13534737